# Processing - "unexpected token: void"

Tags: processing

I am using the below code to simulate "Purple Rain" (from The Coding Train on 
YouTube).

```java
Class Drop(){
  float x = width/2;
  float y = 0;
  float yspeed = 1;

  void fall(){
    y = y + yspeed;
  }
  void show(){
    stroke(138, 43, 226);  //purple rain
    line(x, y, x, y+10);
  }

}
```

However, I am getting the error `unexpected token: void` on line 6:

```java
void fall(){
```

I can't see any syntax errors - could someone suggest why I am getting this error?

Comment: Is this all of the code you have in the Processing editor?

Comment: `Class Drop() { /* ... */ }`? I see two errors in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have a syntax error. The `Class` keyword should be `class` with a lower-case `c`. You should also not have parenthesis after the class name.

Also, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080424/class-nebula-does-not-exist/44080444#44080444). The Processing editor doesn't like when you only have a `class` definition without Processing functions like `setup()` and `draw()`.

Side note: you might want to try approaching problems like this with a "what syntax error am I not seeing?" mentality instead of saying "I have no syntax errors" - the compiler doesn't lie, so saying you have no syntax mistakes comes off as a little bit presumptuous.